# What scriptures did Kalidasa use in his Raghuvamsa?

Tags: ramayana, scripture

[Kalidasa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalidasa) is most famous for being a Sanskrit playwright who wrote plays based on stories from  Hindu scripture.   But Kalidasa also composed epic poetry on the same subject, most notably [*Raghuvamsa*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raghuva%E1%B9%83%C5%9Ba), an epic poem about members of the Raghu dynasty, including Rama.

My question is, what are the specific Hindu scriptures that *Raghuvamsa* is based on?  Did Kalidasa ever mention what sources he relied upon to compose it?  Or have later scholars surmised where the content of *Raghuvamsa* originates from?

I assume that the Valmiki Ramayana was one of the sources used, particularly the Uttara Kanda, but what other sources were used?

Comment: What do you mean by "scriptures" here? Of course Kalidasa was acquainted with the Veda and Upanishads, as with various shastras (of dharma, artha, kama, also vyakarana etc) and their influence is visible throughout his works. (Dr. Ganesh's "Kalidasana Kavya-samskriti" (in Kannada) is wonderful on this topic.) If you mean works on the Ramaya specifically, then V. Raghavan's _The Ramayana Tradition in Asia_ and _Sanskrit Ramayanas Other Than Valmiki's_ are useful references (most are later than Kalidasa though). Of course as a mahakavi Kalidasa also used his own creativity to draw from.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR I'm specifically interested in the sources Kalidasa used for information about Rama and his ancestors.  He might have taken artistic license in certain places, but to the extent that he drew from existing sources I want to know what those sources were.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the clarification. I'll keep an eye out, and if I come across the answer to this somewhere in my reading, I'll make sure to come back here and post an answer. Regards,

Comment: [Do](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/689/277) we need tag for literature in addition to scripture?